# Error ! Package xkeyval Error: xkeyval loaded before \documentclass

Tags: errors

I'm getting this error

! Package xkeyval Error: xkeyval loaded before \documentclass.

but I don't have a package thats called xkeyval

```
\input{Header/Packages}

\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169,xcolor=table]{beamer}
```

\this is what in Header/Packages

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym,mathtools}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{textcomp}
\RequirePackage{xsavebox} % xlrbox
\RequirePackage{media9}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{wrapfig}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{pdfpages} 
\RequirePackage{esvect}  
\RequirePackage{makecell}
\RequirePackage{relsize}
\RequirePackage{textpos}
\RequirePackage{siunitx}[=v2] 
\RequirePackage{steinmetz}   
\RequirePackage{gensymb}  
\RequirePackage{multirow} 
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\RequirePackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\RequirePackage{pgfplotstable} 
\RequirePackage{arydshln}
\RequirePackage{bm} 
\RequirePackage{booktabs}   
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{calligra}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{pgfgantt}
\RequirePackage{pdflscape}
\RequirePackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{epstopdf}
\RequirePackage{multicol}
\RequirePackage[RPvoltages, american,cuteinductors]{circuitikz}[=v0.8.3]
\RequirePackage{textcomp}
\RequirePackage{xcolor} 
\RequirePackage[pages=some]{background}
```

So what is the problem here

Comment: you are loading tons of package before \documentclass and one of them will load xkeyval. Move your input behind documentclass (and shorten it, loading too many unneeded packages will only make debugging difficult).

Comment: why are you loading any packages before `\documentclass`  that is not the intended way to use latex

Comment: the problem is the \RequirePackage[pages=some]{background}, but I need it to include a background in my slides so how can I solve this problem

Comment: I'm confident, that most of packages you load before `beamer` document class are useless in presentations. Some of them are loaded by `beamer` again, there are also some loaded twice. For background if slides you not need `background` package. For this has `beamer` own support (see `beamer` documentation).

Comment: I figured out what is the problem, but I don't know why this is causing the problem. Its the name of the main file "Main", when I changed it to "Paper" it worked